# how to make sed match a pattern with multiple lines

Tags: multithreading, bash, awk, sed

## Background

I use sed a lot to track logs that begin with lines that matches a certain pattern. I use this command:

```
sed -ne '/pattern/ p' infile >outfile
```

In the code, I simply prepend log lines with identifiers so that I can filter using them later on (my identifiers are order number and thread number.. so for example this log line:

```
9/14/2017 10:19:58 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41361::Failed Checkout
```

is for order 7123 thread 41361. So the sed command above (if I'm filtering for all logs pertaining to order `7123`) will look like:

```
sed -ne '/ORD7123/ p' infile >outfile
```

## Problem

The problem happens when the log for a single order/thread combination spans multiple lines like so:

```
9/14/2017 10:19:58 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41361::Failed Checking Out With Credit Card for # 3 times. Error: {
  "order": "country is required",
  "credit_card": "year is not a valid year"
}.
9/14/2017 10:19:59 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41347::Successfully Got a something Solution
```

using the above sed command, my output will look like this

```
9/14/2017 10:19:58 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41361::Failed Checking Out With Credit Card for # 3 times. Error: {
9/14/2017 10:19:59 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41347::Successfully Got a something Solution
```

## Suggestions/Analysis

We faced this problem before (where we had control over the creation of logs) and the way we dealt with it was by replacing new lines by `/n` or something like that. In this case I don't have much control over the logs creation, and so I must deal with the logs as is

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` should be able to handle this that can work the way **logstash** works and collects log messages on multiple lines. Looking at your example, it appears that you want to capture text between `{ ... }` that goes over multiple lines. Hence you can use something link this:

```
awk '/ORD7123/{if (/{$/) p=1; print; next} p; p && /^}/{p=0}' file.log
```

---

If you don't always have `{ ... }` as shown in example logs then you can use this `awk` command:

```
awk '/ORD7123/ {p=NR} NR==p+1 {p = (/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4} / ? 0 : NR)} p' file

9/14/2017 10:19:58 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41361::Failed Checking Out With Credit Card for # 3 times. Error: {
  "order": "country is required",
  "credit_card": "year is not a valid year"
}.
9/14/2017 10:19:59 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41347::Successfully Got a something Solution
```

This `awk` command looks for starting date pattern in every log line and if it doesn't find it, it is considered continuation of previous log message.

Comment: That is what I would like to know from OP if log message will always have `{ ... }` or not.

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk -v p="ORD7123" '$0~p{ print; 
           while(getline nl > 0 && (nl!~/^[0-9]+\/[0-9]{2}/ || nl~p)){ 
               print nl 
           } 
       }' inputfile
```

The exemplary output:

```
9/14/2017 10:19:58 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41361::Failed Checking Out With Credit Card for # 3 times. Error: {
  "order": "country is required",
  "credit_card": "year is not a valid year"
}.
9/14/2017 10:19:59 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41347::Successfully Got a something Solution
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/ORD7123/!d;:b;n;/^..\?\/..\?\/.... ..:..:.. /ba;bb' file
```

Match on the required string (`ORD7123`) otherwise delete the line. On a match, read and print subsequent lines until a line beginning with a date and time, then check for the required string.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, **that is all**. You're not trying to do a simple substitution on an individual line so you shouldn't be considering sed. Just use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[0-9]/ { prt() }
{ rec = (rec=="" ? "" : rec ORS) $0 }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( rec ~ /ORD7123/) {
        print rec
    }
    rec = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
9/14/2017 10:19:58 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41361::Failed Checking Out With Credit Card for # 3 times. Error: {
  "order": "country is required",
  "credit_card": "year is not a valid year"
}.
9/14/2017 10:19:59 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41347::Successfully Got a something Solution
```

It can very easily be tweaked to remove the newlines in the middle of the records if you'd like further processing to be simpler by just changing `ORS` to `OFS` (or any other string you like) where the record is being compiled:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[0-9]/ { prt() }
{ rec = (rec=="" ? "" : rec OFS) $0 }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( rec ~ /ORD7123/) {
        print rec
    }
    rec = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
9/14/2017 10:19:58 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41361::Failed Checking Out With Credit Card for # 3 times. Error: {   "order": "country is required",   "credit_card": "year is not a valid year" }.
9/14/2017 10:19:59 AM:::   ORD7123::TH41347::Successfully Got a something Solution
```